# How to generate Labelname from a variable? (how to cast a string to UILabel)

Tags: swift, uilabel

I want to refer to a label based on the title of the button pressed.

I have a plenty of buttons, that I connected together in a single action. I want to be able to refer to only one label, that corresponds to the name of button pressed.

The Label names are: aLabel, bLabel, cLabel ...
The buttons pressed are titled "a", "b", "c"...

I ame creating the string with name of the label i want to refer to, but I can't use it as label name to change this particular label values.

I want to use this string to refer to the corresponding label, to change it title, color, and so on.

I tried, casting, looking for a function that changes strings into UILabels. I was also thinking about an array with pointers to the Labels, but I didn't succed even with establishing a pointer to a single Label...

```
//My code

@IBOutlet weak var a: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var b: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var c: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var aLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var bLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var cLabel: UILabel!

var currentLabel : String

@IBAction func FieldDisplay(_ sender: UIButton) {
  currentLabel = sender.currentTitle! + "Label"
  currentLabel.text = "OK"
}

//what I tried
(UILabel)currentLabel.text = "OK"
currentLabel = currentLabel.to.UIlabel
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When interface objects are associated in multiple pairs like this — a series of button–label pairs, as you have it — there are two approaches commonly used. One is to assign each pair a *tag*. For example, in the storyboard, the first button would have tag 1, and the first label would have tag 101. Then the second button would have tag 2, and the second label would have tag 102. And so on.

So now in your IBAction function you look at the `tag` of the `sender`, add 100 to it, and call `viewWithTag` on your `view` to find the corresponding label.

The other possibility is to use *outlet collections*. Instead of three button outlets you have one array-of-button outlet; so too for the labels. Now in your IBAction function you get the `firstIndex` of the button in its array; that, if you've set this up correctly, is the index of the corresponding label in *its* array.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all outlets and create 2 collections

```
@IBOutlet var allBts: [UIButton]!
@IBOutlet var allLbls: [UILabel]!
```

then hook all labels / btns to each , and set a tag for each group ( lbl1 && btn1 tag = 0 , lbl2 && btn2 tag = 1 and so on)

```
@IBAction func FieldDisplay(_ sender: UIButton) {
  allLbls[sender.tag].text = sender.currentTitle! + "Label" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **value(forKey:)** method

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let currentLabel = value(forKey: sender.currentTitle! + "Label") as? UILabel {
        currentLabel.text = "OK"
    }
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1412591-value